# Is there way to store JSON documents in AWS S3, with support to querying the data with mongodb aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

We're in phase of shifting older mongodb docs to aws S3. S3 supports JSON documents to store ([reference1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/working-with-json.html)). Also it does allow basic querying through SQL-like language ([reference2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html)). We're thinking about using Athena for querying which also uses SQL-like query language. Is there way for querying JSON documents with mongodb aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

You can query JSON documents stored in S3 using the aggregation pipeline using MongoDB [Atlas Datalake](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/data-lake).

Comment: Hi @Joe just want to have your advice. Is it good practice to replace storage model from mongodb to S3 entirely and use Atlas Datalake for querying?

Comment: There is a trade off in query speed. MongoDB Datalake is many times slow than that a full blown database instance, but the storage is much cheaper.